# Mark a flag as helpful with a message

Tags: script, bookmarklet

Sparked by [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/202983/is-this-really-the-appropriate-response-to-a-helpful-flag#comment646276_202983)

> Strictly-speaking, any moderator can leave a message along with Helpful, @Bill - there's just no UI for it.

The following bookmarklet, when clicked after loading the mod flag dashboard, will give an additional option (with a textbox) "custom helpful" which lets the moderator mark a flag as helpful and leave a message (similar to a decline message) with the flag.

```
javascript:function manishCustomHelpfulappendPopup(postid){$('<div id=manishCustomHelpful><input id=manishCustomHelpfulText type=text style="width:90%"></input><br><input id=manishCustomHelpfulButton type=button value="Custom Helpful"></input></div>').insertBefore('input[type=button][value=helpful]');$('#manishCustomHelpfulButton').click(function(){$.post("/messages/delete-moderator-messages/"+postid+"/"+renderTimeTicks+"?valid=true",{fkey:StackExchange.options.user.fkey,comment:$('#manishCustomHelpfulText').val()});$('[title="close this popup (or hit Esc)"]').click();$('#flagged-'+postid).hide();});};$("table.flagged-posts.moderator .dismiss-all").click(function(){var  postid =($(this).closest('tr[id^="flagged-"]').attr('id').replace("flagged-", ""));setTimeout(function(){manishCustomHelpfulappendPopup(postid)},200);});
```

Comment: Wait, one of the most requested features is actually possible? WHY is there no UI for this?!?! +1

Comment: Nice! May I steal this for [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch)? And if yes, would you mind helping me test it before it's released to make sure it really works? (It turns out that I _can_ actually trick the SE UI into thinking I'm a mod well enough to test this code, but only up to a point -- probably fortunately, it doesn't let me _actually_ dismiss any flags.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sure. I don't mind helping out on the SOUP project either, I have a bunch of suggestions/snippets of my own

Comment: Excellent. I made a few tweaks to you code while I was at it (the most visible one being that I moved the custom button and text field below the normal "helpful" button). Can you test [this version of SOUP (v1.5.1+)](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/devel/SOUP.user.js) ([source](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/devel/SOUP.user.js)) and tell me a) if it works, and b) if you think the changes I made are improvements or not? (Also, feel free to steal any improvements you do like. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen [it works](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds2Vr.png) ([ui](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gaFmc.png) ). Maybe a better UI would be where there is only one helpful button, and if the reason box is empty it uses the normal helpful (using `$.click()`, because the normal helpful has a load of error checking magic that mine doesn't). All you have to do is `.hide()` the normal helpful and `.click()` it for empty text

Comment: @IlmariKaronen (working on this in a fork)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen pull requested the improvement. Tested.

Comment: Thanks! I merged your pull request and added some rudimentary error handling. Can you give it another try?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen got some work and sleep, ping me tomorrow :)